# Access tokens with Graph Api stopped working even after upgrading to API 2.0

Tags: api, facebook-graph-api

my app was pulling feeds to my site for over a year, and recently stopped working late this month(23/03/2015).

I debugged the application, and still don't know why my access token is reported malformed. Here is a sample of a token which to me perplexes me as at the end there is a # tag in it, something I don't expect with QueryString access tokens:

AQD2pAp0kqILBZ9ysXGarDVdmcnnknRgnLvnLdml2TuiLXH8grq8mHkyBCE3jjoEahyMl17myD7ldp1DDWRYEIP9EEnwSHUU5-sZk3mZv6p5YTLpfTVQntYeuuYbIYEn13e3PkF2_cCQbRU2R769xr_Cj0j3Gf_HygWElOQq3BtivxTgN4Db1HfEzrIpnR7309sAZAwKJKbTGw07KukL51oVn1di0gcO2dn5ffv5V4MEb4RuVLLNrcjZWbVPB7Ktyiy62Gw-64ypMqyx2zj_0quZKFlgV0fBE_TY3K_iMr-XEGuodId1hk0n7k89DUjXa40#*=*

Looking at my application on Facebook(app), it is clear that I should expect access tokens on request from Query String.

Something is definitely wrong, as this access token reports a malformed access token. This is a recent bug that has just cropped up so I think.

Any body know about this problem? I can't access my feeds from my facebook profile using this access token to expose to my web based application.

Any help or suggestions are welcome.

Kind regards
Martin Okello.

Comment: have you tried creating a new access token?

Comment: I generate an access token as per the requirements of every call to Facebook According to the graph api. Everything was working fine until last week when I couldn't read any posts from my profile. The request for an access token I make via v2.0 api call. this sends me a query string with access token which I then use to request my profile post

Comment: I always request an access token each time before reading feeds off my profile. using v2.0 Of the graph api sends me a typical access token as shown in my post Above. This clearly isn't a format of access tokens with a # in it At the end. graph api sends a query string labeled access token and each time I use the access token I get an oath exception malformed access token

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you were using the `read_stream` permission which is no longer granted to apps. You should try to regenerated an Access Token with the new `user_posts` permission and use this Access Token instead.

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_3_new_features
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.3#reference-read_stream

Comment: I have been using the unversioned graph api. this stopped working on the 22nd March though.  So I changed the url by prefixing /v2.0 to request access token

Comment: I am using v2.0. Graph api. I don't particularly use read_stream. I just request an access token then use what the graph api provides. This started failing on 23 or 22nd this month

Comment: I added the user_posts permissions which acording to Facebook requirements  is given to all apps that already had read_stream permission. It still does not provide me with a typically expected  access token. Still access token requested via the Facebook app gives me # as part of it towards the end of the toke  like the one I posted on the question